# Start up command for Azure Linux Webapp

Tags: azure

I am deploying a Django application on an Azure Linux Webapp.

I've followed [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-deploy-app-service-on-linux) to provide a `startup.txt`. In my `startup.txt`, I have the following:

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 configs.wsgi
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py migrate --settings=configs.base_settings
```

On deployments, when I check the logs, only the first command runs. How do we run more than one command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they call it "custom startup command" (singular) for a reason ;)

So what you can do is put all your commands in a single line using a separator of your choice:

1. Semicolon `;` if you want to run the next command regardless of the previous one being failed or not: `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 configs.wsgi ; pip install -r requirements.txt ; python manage.py migrate --settings=configs.base_settings`
2. Double ampersand `&&` if you want to run the next command only if the previous one has succeeded: `gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 configs.wsgi && pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py migrate --settings=configs.base_settings`